# Inappropriate link in advert (yes or no or something else?)

Tags: bug

I keep reporting this advert because I can't disable it and it's annoying me. Nothing appears to be being done about it. So, why does pressing the ad-choices button take you to some random yahoo site instead of the ad-choices so that I can disable it?

[image]

### UPDATE

SE Adverts no longer are seen on my PC as of 30th March 2022. I don't know what happened other than the advert picture changed and, I clicked on the ad-choice link and, it allowed me to disable it properly. Fingers crossed it won't happen again.

Comment: You have 371k rep. How come you see ads? I believe ads are removed at 200rep. I don't see any on my side, and I have no ad blocker. Anyway, I think on the main meta there will be better answers for this: this is not site-specific.

Comment: @dim I have no idea why I see ads and I didn't realize that above a certain rep you shouldn't.

Comment: I'm not quite sur about this, though. This page of the help center serms to contradict my thoughts: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads. But when I saw your screenshot, I felt like it didn't look like what I usually see, but rather something I see on sites on which I have no rep. And I checked, I don't have ads at all on EE.SE. Strange.

Comment: @dim do you see the microsoft azure ad (as per the picture in my question above) on this link: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610170/any-preferred-sequence-for-low-pass-filter-and-attenuator

Comment: OK the ad is there but the picture has changed - scroll down a bit - it's on the right hand side. Just checked again and it looks like the picture in the ad alternates - it still takes you to yahoo when you click ad-choices though.

Comment: Honestly, I see no ad at all. Here is what the page looks like on my side: https://i.stack.imgur.com/juESA.png

Comment: I smell some covert fixing is going on. I can no longer see the ad for azure but, clearly I once did @dim

Comment: Amendment: I can't see ads on my iPad but I **can see them** on my laptop (as reported before).

Comment: I wasn't even aware that there are ads on SE sites :P but then I have both an ad-block browser extension and a [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) filtering my LAN's DNS so ...

Comment: Did you try user profile -> edit profile -> preferences -> enable advertisements = off.

Comment: @Lundin I have ads disabled as per this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjsgx.png

Comment: I had no idea that there were ads :-). I get a stack overflow teams ad at left - which my brain filters out. Otherwise I see none on Android phone or Windows.

Comment: I'm so used to seeing ads I guess it would be strange not to see them. However, it does appear that I shouldn't be seeing ads so, how to stop them @RussellMcMahon - the original question still stands of course - why, when clicking on the advert's ad-choices button does it go to a yahoo page.